# Error Loading Stylesheets in Express 3.x

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So I'm having an problem loading my stylesheets in my express project. When I was using express 2.5.8 my styles were being loaded correctly, but when I updated to 3.x the styles started failing to load. The views get rendered but without any styles.

I'm using node, express 3.x, jade, and bootstrap. My styles are in `public/stylesheets/*`.

UPDATE: It seems that for some reason `layout.jade` isn't being rendered.

Here' my `server.js`

```
require('coffee-script');
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express'),
            flash = require('connect-flash');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('port', 3000);
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(flash());
  app.use(require('connect-assets')());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ 
    dumpExceptions: true, 
    showStack: true 
  }));
});

app.configure('test', function () {
  app.set('port', 3001);
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

require('./apps/landing-page/routes')(app);
require('./apps/authentication/routes')(app);
require('./apps/home/routes')(app);
require('./apps/register/routes')(app);


app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.settings.port, app.settings.env);
```

Here's my main `layout.jade` view:

```
!!!
html
  head
    title= title
    script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', media='screen', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/app.css')

    script(src='javascripts/bootstrap.js')

    |   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    |   <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/ie.css">
    |   <![endif]-->

    |   <!-- IE Fix for HTML5 Tags -->
    |   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    |     <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    |   <![endif]-->

  body 
    !=body


script(src='javascripts/app.js')
```

And here's one of my routes:

```
routes = (app) ->
    app.get '/home', (req, res) ->
        res.render "#{__dirname}/views/home",
        title: 'Home | SiteName'
        stylesheet: 'home'


module.exports = routes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that layout rendering was set to `false` per default in Express 3, so try and add following to your configuration:

```
app.set('view options', { layout: true });
```

**Update:** [The migration guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) state that the concept of layouts and partials have been removed altogether. Instead, use [Jade's template inheritance](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#template-inheritance).

**/views/layout**

```
!!! 5
head
    // all your header elements
body
    block content
```

**/views/home**

Add the following at the top:

```
extends layout

block content
    // the stuff you want to have in your content block
```

For more info, take a look at [this guide](http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/).

Comment: I might just put the css/js declarations in each separate view's head, but I feel like that's kind of hacky. My layout should be rendering first...

Comment: @ConnorBlack Updated with info on how to replace layout with Jade blocks instead

Comment: @ConnorBlack You're most welcome! Also, you might want to take a look at my project [express-assets](https://github.com/mekwall/express-assets). Check the example to see how it works :)

Answer (score 2):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

must be before

```
app.use(app.router);
```